# ¿Hay alguna forma de dejar fija la primera fila del excel con Laravel Excel 3.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

Estoy usando maatwebsite/excel 3.1 en un proyecto de Laravel 5.8

Necesito dejar fija la primera fila al exportar el excel. Lo que se conocía en la [versión 2.1 como Freeze rows](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/freeze.html).

Aquí está la manera de hacerlo antes de la versión 3

```
Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {

    $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {

        $sheet->freezeFirstColumn();

    });

})->export('xls');
```

Comment: Creo que ahora debes usar este Trait `WithCustomStartCell` y definir un collection con los datos que quieres.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La forma de hacerlo a partir de la versión 3.0 es con la forma nativa de PhpSpreadsheet.

Consultad este ejemplo si lo necesitais.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66629820/8359374

```
class SomeExport implements WithEvents
{
   public function registerEvents(): array
   {
       return [
           AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
               $workSheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();
               $workSheet->freezePane('A2');
           },
       ];
   }
}
```

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/260427)

Comment: Hecho. Me han contestado desde el portal en inglés, pero quería dejarlo por aquí para la comunidad hispanohablante, pues no hay una respuesta tan concisa como esta.